# How to check if a string value does not exist in another dataframe?

Tags: python, dataframe

I have 2 dataframes to focus: df_hours and new_df

I want to check if a string value of a dataframe(df_hours) does not exist in the whole dataframe(new_df).

For e.g.
df_hours has a 'Category' column with string values 'A','B','C' etc.
I want to check if 'A' does not exist in new_df.

I have 2 for loops and inside it I have the following if condition:

```
for i in range(len(df_hours)):
  for j in range(len(df_hours_copy)):

   if df_hours.iloc[i,1] == df_hours_copy.iloc[j,1] and (~df_hours.iloc[i,1].isin(new_df)):
```

How can I code the second part of the if (the one after the 'and')?

The idea:
By the code after `and`, I just want to check if that value does not exist in new_df then insert some values from `df_hours` to `new_df`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `any` and a list comprehension to gather all missing values in new_df from you series :

```
[value for value in df_hours["Category"].unique() if not (new_df==value).any().any()]
```

Calling `.any()` once will look for the value column-wise. The second call will check if any *True* is in the resulting series.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure what exactly you are trying to do with the two loops, but you could use masks to filter your df, for example:

```
mask = ~df_new[col_new].isin(df_hours[col].values)
df[mask]
```

where `col_new` is a certain column of `df_new` and `col` is a certain column from `df_hours` and you could look on the columns if required.

Comment: I have edited the question. Please let me know if you need any more details.

Comment: By filtering as I have done above, you will get a subset of `df_new` where the values are not in `df_hours[col]`. What values do you want to assign to that subset of the dataframe? Do you want to assign it a new value for all entries or a different value for each single entry?